# wp_enqueue_scripts doesn't work for template pages

Tags: javascript, page-template, wp-enqueue-script, child-theme

In my child theme's `functions.php` I wrote :

```
function add_js() {

   echo "path is : ".get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/script.js';
   wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js');
```

where `script.js` contains this dummy script : `alert("something");`

This script works everywhere except for my template pages. Though the path displayed thanks to the echo is correct. I noticed that while I was trying to call my script only from template pages, thanks to `is_page_template()` conditional tag.

My page templates are located at the root of my child theme's folder, I guess this is the source of the issue but I can't explain why. Any idea please ?

Comment: Where did you add `is_page_template()` ?

Comment: I added it in the beginning but as I had the same problem as stated above, I removed it. In its actual form, shouldn't my code work for every kind of page/post ?

Comment: Yes it should work. `alert()` isn't working doesn't mean script isn't included. Did you check the page source and browser console ?

Comment: sure, I checked that in the first place. Script isn't included in the template pages

Comment: yes. All the other files (style.css, functions.php...) located in my child theme's directory work normally

Comment: It is hard to say in one answer that what's the problem. try changing the handle name from `script` to something unique, Increase the priority of action from default 10 to something 99 OR check in template code what is there, replace it with `index.php` code just for debugging.

Comment: I changed the name without any effect. Same thing for the priority. Including the script "manually" worked : `<script type="text/javascript" src=<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/mycustomscript.js'?>></script>?` Though the problem remains the same...

Comment: Try including script in header instead of footer by making last parameter as `false` !

Comment: Do your template pages contain the `wp_footer` function to output the scripts?

Comment: Solved thanks to you ! As I tested with a "basic" template it worked, then I noticed I hadn't any get_footer() ! Now it works for both "true" and "false" parameters, and is loaded in the header or the footer. Thank you both !